# Can the COM and NO terminals of a mechanical relay be used interchangeably?

Tags: relay, mechanical

I have a 240v 30a relay and for layout purposes it may be helpful to orient the relay such that the NO contact is where I’d like the COM contact to be.

As it is a NO relay can I simply connect my input power to the NO terminal and the output to the com? Is there something I’m missing that would make this an unwise idea?

This is the relay I'm using,[T9AS1D12-12](http://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=srchrtrv&DocNm=1308242_T9A&DocType=DS&DocLang=English),  but I'm actually interested in the answer in a more general sense, if there are typical reasons why one could not reverse the terminals.

Comment: Is it a (electro)mechanical relay? Or Solid State?

Comment: This would be easier to answer if you post the datasheet or at least the part number of the relay.

Comment: Depends on the relay, need more info.

Comment: @EugeneSh. the post topic specifically mentions a mechanical relay :-)

Comment: I've updated with a link to the particular relay although I'm really interested in the general sense if it matters which way it is wired up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the contact is fully isolated from the coil then it will be fine.

[image]

*Figure 1. Various relay contact arrangements. Source: [Telus.net](http://www3.telus.net/cbradley/relay3.JPG).*

The likely reason for the "common" terminology is that variations of the relay will include a changeover version which requires clear identification of the common terminal. In Figure 1 this would be terminal 30.

Comment: TIL there's a kind of relay that has less than five pins.

Comment: What does "TIL" mean? Relay 1 has four pins. I don't understand your comment.

Comment: TIL -> today I learned.